# How to draw rectangle in ZX plane in SolveSpace?

Tags: drawing

I want to draw (for example, a rectanle) in a plane, different than XY in [SolveSpace](https://solvespace.com/index.pl). I selected ZX but it doesn't want to draw

[image]

How to force it to work?